# Date function for following month

Tags: sql-server

What function can I use to get the date for the following month, in the format 201907?

The following code snippet returns 201907, but I need a function that will always return the next month

```
select 
    convert(varchar(6), DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 7, 1), 112)
```

Comment: Have you have a look at `DATEADD`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DATEADD`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(6), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()), 112)
```